# Minimum number of givens for General Sudoku of size $n^2 \times n^2$

Tags: reference-request, board-games, sudoku

[Here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Minimum_number_of_givens) it is well known that the minimal number of givens for a size $9 \times 9$ board of Sudoku requires 17 "givens" in order to be solved (i.e., no puzzle can be solved with $\le 16$ givens).

What is the minimal number of givens for a size $n^2 \times n^2$ board? Is there a table of "best-known" minimal values?

I'm speculating that there is only an asymptotic/approximate bound as the $n=3$ case was not known, let alone higher values of $n$. For $n=4$, the best-known is 55, and $n=5$ is 151.

Comment: That link says the proof that 17 "givens" are required was only obtained through exhaustive computer search.  Therefore, there's not likely to be a known formula that works for general $n$; and when $n$ is large, exhaustive search to find the exact answer is not likely to be feasible.  Asking for a table of best known bounds is reasonable, though.

Comment: @D.W. I was just wondering if there is a known proof that at least $f(n)$ givens is required or something. A table would be more helpful though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum number of clues to fully specify any sudoku?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/163/minimum-number-of-clues-to-fully-specify-any-sudoku)

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that question asks about 9x9 sudoku, while this asks about generalization.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A198297

Answer (score 2):

The minimum number of clues for a puzzle of $n^2$ x $n^2$ is known for $n = 2$ (4 x 4 Sudoku), of which the **minimum clues is 4** (25% of cells filled). There are 13 such non-equivalent puzzles. (based on info at "enjoysudoku.com").

The minimum number of clues for a puzzle of $n^2$ x $n^2$ is also known for $n = 3$ (9 x 9 Sudoku), of which the **minimum clues is 17** (about 21.0% of cells filled). About 49,000 such non-equivalent Sudokus have been discovered.

For $n = 4$ (16 x 16), the fewest clues known in any puzzle is 55 (about 21.5% of cells filled), but it is not known if this is the fewest possible. (based on info at "enjoysudoku.com").

For $n = 5$ (25 x 25), little work has also been done to find the fewest clues possible, and comparatively few Sudokus of this size have been constructed. One 25 x 25 Sudoku is known to have 328 clues. So from a cursory study, the fewest clues for (n=5) is 328 or fewer (about 52% or fewer cells filled). Note: this Sudoku was not an attempt to be an example with few clues. I listed it only to provide an initial upper bound.

Comment: For n in {0,1}, the minimum is zero. ​ ​

Comment: Well, is it proven at least that number of givens tends to become closer to number of cells as $n$ grows? Maybe some upper bound on limit ($\le 1$) is known? Or $1$ is tight bound?

Comment: Seems like an open problem well into to the delve of research.